# How to bind the microservice locally in Eureka without docker host name?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, microservices, netflix-eureka

In my local environment, I am trying to bind a microservice by up it locally. But instead of bind it with the computer username it bind as below.

**UP (1) - host.docker.internal:mySampleMicroService:8096**

but **it should bind with computer name instead of host.docker.internal** part.Thought this due to docker install in my computer, then uninstall it and checked it, but the issues was same

even with docker it doesnot show any image(just check it with 'docker image ls' command)

**How can I bind the locally up service with my machine name in NETFLIX EUREKA?**

Comment: got fixed it by editing the host file. remove the host.docker.internal domain for 127.0.0.1. then restart the computer. it works now.